# CSS - Is there a better way to create scrolling repeated text that appears and disaapears from the very edge of the box?

Tags: css, layout, css-animations

```css
.container {
      font-family: sans-serif;
      font-size: 30px;
      position: relative;
    /*   border: 1px solid #000; */
      width: 90%;
      margin: 0 auto;
      overflow: hidden;
      text-align: center;
      margin-top: 10px;
    }
    
    .individual {
      animation: scroll 500ms linear infinite;
      }
    
    @keyframes scroll {
      100% {
        transform: translateY(100%);
      }
    }
    
    .overlay-1 {
      position: absolute;
      top: 0;
      left: 0;
      width: 100%;
      height: 100%;
      background-color: none;
      outline: 20px solid #fff;
      outline-offset: -20px;
    }
    
    .overlay-2 {
      position: absolute;
      top: 0;
      left: 0;
      width: 100%;
      height: 100%;
      opacity: 1;
      background-color: none;
      z-index: 2;
      outline: 2px solid #000;
      outline-offset: -20px;
    }
```

```html
<div class="container">
 
<div class="individual">
  <div class"words">HELLO TO YOU</div>
</div>
<div class="individual">
  <div class"words">HELLO TO YOU</div>
</div>
<div class="individual">
  <div class"words">HELLO TO YOU</div>
</div>
<div class="individual">
  <div class"words">HELLO TO YOU</div>
</div>
<div class="individual">
  <div class"words">HELLO TO YOU</div>
</div>
<div class="individual">
  <div class"words">HELLO TO YOU</div>
</div>

<div class="overlay-1"></div>
<div class="overlay-2"></div>
  
</div>
```

I'm trying to figure out how to recreate an effect used on this site:
https://inthecity.strelka.com/en

It's the effect in the boxes where a word like "conference" is repeated over and over in a scrolling list. Looking at their source code, it seems like they repeat the same word in a series of identical divs and then animate them in an infinite loop with transform: translate. That part was simple enough, but it was harder to get the top line to enter the box from "outside" the box, in the same way that the bottom text exits the box, if that makes sense. The top line just appears suddenly.

I solved it with an overlaid box that has an outline with a negative offset that acts like a inner mask around the edges, then another box to provide a border.

But I'm wondering if there is a simpler way to solve this problem?

Any help or ideas would be great, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is these 2 lines:

```
outline: 20px solid #fff;
outline-offset: -20px;
```

I have implimented the snippet below with the correct code.

```css
.container {
      font-family: sans-serif;
      font-size: 30px;
      position: relative;
    /*   border: 1px solid #000; */
      width: 90%;
      overflow: hidden;
      text-align: center;
      margin-top: 10px;
    }
    
    .individual {
      animation: scroll 1000ms linear infinite;
      }
    
    @keyframes scroll {
      100% {
        transform: translateY(100%);
      }
    }
    
    .overlay-1 {
      position: absolute;
      top: 0;
      left: 0;
      width: 100%;
      height: 100%;
      background-color: none;
      outline: 50px solid #fff;
      outline-offset: -30px;
    }
    
    .overlay-2 {
      position: absolute;
      top: 0;
      left: 0;
      width: 100%;
      height: 100%;
      opacity: 1;
      background-color: none;
      
      outline: 2px solid #000;
      outline-offset: -20px;
    }
```

```html
<div class="container">
 
<div class="individual">
  <div class"words">HELLO TO YOU</div>
</div>
<div class="individual">
  <div class"words">HELLO TO YOU</div>
</div>
<div class="individual">
  <div class"words">HELLO TO YOU</div>
</div>
<div class="individual">
  <div class"words">HELLO TO YOU</div>
</div>
<div class="individual">
  <div class"words">HELLO TO YOU</div>
</div>
<div class="individual">
  <div class"words">HELLO TO YOU</div>
</div>

<div class="overlay-1"></div>
<div class="overlay-2"></div>
  
</div>
```

Comment: Sorry, I might not have been clear in my original question - I have the effect working as intended in my snippet, I'm just wondering if there is a better way to achieve the same result. Your changes cut the text off before the box edges which is not what I'm looking for. Thanks anyway!

Comment: @PS10916 Sorry for the misunderstanding, I made with my snippet a way to make the text transition smoother from the top, as I saw in your snippet, it just pops in out of nowhere, so I changed it to make it smoother. - TheCrafters001